# AES encryption with plain text key using bash openssl

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a string using AES CBC. The output of the online tool (http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) and the bash openssl command do not match. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

```
key = 12345678912345678912345678912345
iv="e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" #using the one generated by online tool
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in input.txt -out output.txt -K $key -iv $iv
```

EDIT - settings I've used online are -

```
Input type - plain text
Function - AES
Mode - CBC
Key - (plain) - 12345678912345678912345678912345
Init Vector - e9 0e 89 a2 27 7f 4f 3b 6a 20 80 d2 7f 73 42 66
```

Comment: Maybe openssl is doing things differently that that web tool... I've read  [on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase/29139#29139) and [here too](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/31494/63902) by a 159K reputation user, that *"The encryption format used by OpenSSL is non-standard: it is "what OpenSSL does""* and *"the "iteration count" is set by the `enc` command to **1** and cannot be changed (!!!!)"*

Comment: You told openssl to use 256 bit encryption, but only gave it a 128 bit key.  I'm guessing the online tool is only using 128 bit encryption, and so you need to do the same.